# A number x $\in$ (0,1) is normal iff $2^n$x mod 1, n$\in\Bbb{N}$ is uniformly distributed

Tags: combinatorics

I started to learn uniform distribution, and I am not so clear how to prove this statement. How can I relate normal number to uniformly distribution?

Also can someone give more explanation of uniform distribution? I thought it is really interesting that the probability that a set of number hit a certain interval within (0,1) is just the length of that interval. But what are its properties? What kind of sets can have uniform distribution? Examples to help grow a sense of uniform distribution?

Comment: You must have made some mistake, since the clause after the iff doesn't mention $x$, while $2^n \mod 1 = 0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that the binary expansion of $x$ is $(0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots)_{\text{two}}$; then the binary expansion of $2^nx\bmod 1$ is $(0.b_{n+1}b_{n+2}b_{n+3}\ldots)_{\text{two}}$. Now consider any finite bit string $a_1a_2\ldots a_m$. The numbers $2^nx\bmod 1$ are uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$ iff the [asymptotic density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of

$$\{n\in\Bbb N:b_{n+1}\ldots b_{n+m}=a_1\ldots a_m\}$$

is $2^{-m}$. (Look at the intervals $\left(0,\frac1{2^m}\right),\left(\frac1{2^m},\frac2{2^m}\right),\ldots,\left(\frac{2^m-1}{2^m},1\right)$.)

Can you relate this to normality of $x$?